# how can I use pcl's clustering method to cluster 6d data, such as Eigen::Matrix<double,6,1>

Tags: point-cloud-library

I want to cluster 6d data by PCL;

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,6,1> Vector6d;
pcl::search::KdTree<Vector6d>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<Vector6d>);
tree->setInputCloud (pose_cloud);
pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<Vector6d> ec;
ec.setClusterTolerance (0.2); 
ec.setMinClusterSize (1);
ec.setMaxClusterSize (25000)
ec.setSearchMethod (tree);
ec.setInputCloud (pose_cloud);
std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> cluster_indices;
ec.extract (cluster_indices);
```

There will many errors about undefined reference.

The `pcl::PointXYZRGB` seems like a 6d data,  Can I use `pcl::PointXYZRGB` to store my data? But the clustering seems to  only happen in the first three data of XYZ.

Comment: PCL assumed 3D spatial localization of data. As such a lot of algorithms treat xyz specially. Hence the behavior you see. Maybe create a feature request if you desire this in PCL with a use-case.
Moreover, it might be a good idea to use a specialized clustering library since high dimensional data behaves much differently as compared to low dimensional data (euclidean distance loses meaning over manhattan distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eucleadien clustering distance is based on [radius search queries](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/9105e776d9d9070391bac16ac3e4d31fd242433e/segmentation/include/pcl/segmentation/impl/extract_clusters.hpp#L160), which is based on the [point-representation](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/9105e776d9d9070391bac16ac3e4d31fd242433e/kdtree/include/pcl/kdtree/impl/kdtree_flann.hpp#L177). So the templated `PointRepresentation` class is responsible for generating the vector on which the clustering is performed. In the case of `pcl::PointXYZRGB`, only the x-y-z coordinates are vectorized.

**Option 1**

You can override the default `PointRepresentation`, as is shown in the [pair-wise registration tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pairwise_incremental_registration.php).

Example - based on the tutorial, but adapted for pcl::PointXYZINormal (as you're interested in 6 floats, so pcl::PointXYZRGB isn't suitable). Also note that unlike the tutorial the PointRepresentation class should be set to the tree object.

```
class MyPointRepresentation : public pcl::PointRepresentation <pcl::PointXYZINormal>
{
  using pcl::PointRepresentation<pcl::PointXYZINormal>::nr_dimensions_;
public:
  MyPointRepresentation ()
  {
    // Define the number of dimensions
    nr_dimensions_ = 6;
  }

  // Override the copyToFloatArray method to define our feature vector
  virtual void copyToFloatArray (const pcl::PointXYZINormal &p, float * out) const
  {
    out[0] = p.x;
    out[1] = p.y;
    out[2] = p.z;
    out[0] = p.normal_x;
    out[1] = p.normal_y;
    out[2] = p.normal_z;
  }
};

// Instantiate our custom point representation (defined above) and weight the dimensions
MyPointRepresentation point_representation;
float alpha[6] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
point_representation.setRescaleValues (alpha);

pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZINormal>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZINormal>);
tree->setPointRepresentation (boost::make_shared<const MyPointRepresentation> (point_representation));
```

**Option 2**

I think you can use the `pcl::Histogram<N>` point type. I can't find where this is defined, but I believe it is safe to assume that it's point representation is  just it's `N` values.

Comment: Thank you very much. Option 2 can't compile successfully, but the option1 can compile successfully. I will check the clustering result and tell you my check result tomorrow.

Comment: I tested the result of option 1. It works properly!